# Good way to integrate time to a quiz game

Tags: mathematics

I wasn't sure which stack exchange site to pose this question to, so I'm asking it here, I hope it's appropriate. This thing I'm writing for fun is basically a mental math speed quiz game. I'm writing it in javascript and html.

What I want to happen is for there to be a score depending on how fast you finished the quiz and how many you got correct. For an incorrect answer, you get 0 points. But for a correct answer, if you took 5 seconds to solve that question, you get more points than if someone took 8 seconds to answer the question.

This seems trivial but I was thinking about it and I don't really have a good algorithm or equation for judging a performance based on time.

For example: someone answering a question correctly in 5 seconds gets 20 points, someone answering correctly in 10 seconds gets 14 points (not exact figures, just example)

Does someone have an idea of this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be:

```
Score = answer*(MAX_TIME - time_taken)
```

where answer is either 0 or 1 (if it was incorrect or correct)

(MAX_TIME - time_taken) could be the input to some function you create that weighs time taken differently. For example, you might want even small differences in time taken to result in large score differences, and could implement this as:

```
Score = answer*(MAX_TIME - time_taken)^3
```

The important thing you need to do is think about the relationship you want between score and time taken so you can find a function that best suits it.

Comment: I like this idea, simple but could work very well. Then I guess if they took longer than max_time, score = 0

Comment: Yes, or if you wanted to avoid negative scores you could do a check before adding it to the user's total.